# Best GPU for Blender 3D Rendering?

Tags: pc

I was told to create another question, this time for the best GPU I can get for Blender 3D Rendering (Cycles) My total budget or this PC I want to get built (I pick out the parts) is $3,000. These are the first two questions I've asked:

[I need a really good computer that I can get built for Blender 3D rendering and gaming](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7857/i-need-a-really-good-computer-that-i-can-get-built-for-blender-3d-rendering-and)

[Mainboard Recommendations For Built Computer Meant For Rendering (And Gaming)](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8101/mainboard-recommendations-for-built-computer-meant-for-rendering-and-gaming/8104?noredirect=1#comment13405_8104)

Here is a summary of what i have put plain and simple:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/omYa0.jpg

But yeah I have a question there too which would be great if it was answered, thanks!

Comment: OK, to adress the questions formulated in the images. No, the Intel and the AMD CPU have _fundamentally_ different sockets and peripheral circuitry, meaning there's no way to exchange them _and_ keep the same mainboard. As for the Mainboards, I didn't know Amazon doesn't have any MSI ones in stock anymore. The ASUS one will work as well. One only needs to look out for the exact pick when picking the case.

Comment: The difficult thing is, there are two somewhat viable options: 2x GTX1070 or 1x GTX 1080Ti. The former is probably a bit more expensive (each card is at least about 400 USD, plus one potentially needs a beefier PSU), the latter will provide better gaming performance, but may be a few per cent slower and a bit cheaper (700-800 USD, plus a less expensive GPU).

Comment: So of the two I should pick the AMD. Okay, what about the motherboard? MSI is available, but it's $400 which is fine.

Comment: Either mainboard will perform very well, my advice would be to go with the cheaper one at the time of ordering (don't need to waste $50!). Just need to look out for the different formats when picking the case (->note for answerers on that Q&A).

Comment: Try looking into Golem, cloud based Blender rendering. Its still in alpha, but might save you a chunk of change.

Comment: Are you still looking into this question?

Answer (score 1):

[EVGA graphics cards have possibly the best warranty policy](https://www.evga.com/support/warranty/graphics-cards/). This is why I will recommend you an EVGA card (the cards in this case all have the -KR suffix and thus limited 3 year warranty). Performance-wise there is little difference (single-digit per-cents) between the cards so the precise choice doesn't matter much.

So what do you actually want from a graphics card? Raw computation power (from Nvidia because Blender uses those cards better). Now there are two ways to provide this sort of power: Use 2 cheaper cards or use one beefy card. For gaming the case is clear on the second one. In this case it's close. Two GTX 1070s would provide roughl (up to a few per cent again) the same performance as one GTX 1080 Ti. However the 1080 Ti will draw less power overall, will perform better when gaming and will also provide you with 11GB of VRAM in total as opposed to 8GB (meaning more can be stored directly in the fast memory on the card). Also a single 1080Ti will likely be cheaper, leaving more room for other components.

So now that we know what you need, which model should you get? Amazon has 6 different EVGA 1080Ti cards. 1 "founder's edition", 2 with water cooling, 3 with air cooling. The water cooled cards are >$1100 and thus too expensive. I see the founder's edition card critically because it has only one fan and will probably be quite loud becaus of the high RPM required.

This leaves us with the following three air cooled cards:

- [**EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti FTW3 GAMING**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06Y15DWXR) (at 800USD)
- [EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti SC2 GAMING](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06Y13N2B6) (at 770USD)
- [EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti SC Black Edition GAMING](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06Y11DFZ3) (at 770USD)

Given the minimal pricing difference here, I would actually recommend the **FTW3** card, because it has 3 fans as opposed to 2, meaning it probably will be cooled better than the other two (meaning it can run faster for longer). It also features slightly higher clocks meaning it's also faster by default.

[On a technical note](https://www.evga.com/products/product.aspx?pn=11G-P4-6696-KR) for the other components, this cards needs 2x8-pin power connectors and claims to draw 280W. Size-wise it's at 11.8" length and standard dual-slot size, which needs to be adjusted for when picking the case.

Comment: Hey thanks for there reply, sorry man I'm still just really lost. So what parts do you think I should get? For the graphics card, cpu, all of that? I really need a good computer that is mainly for Blender that renders very good and fast for complex animations, preferably under $3,000. Sorry I'm just so lost and dont know anything

Comment: @GodzillaDude for GPU, CPU and mainboard you have recommendations now. Each part requires some research (at least from my side). I can't / won't make an all-in-one recommendation because of this. For your next question the candidates are PSU (power supply unit), RAM (working memory) and persistent storage (HDDs, SSDs, ...). Pick one and ask or pick all three and ask for all three in three questions (this would speed things up).

Comment: SEJPM, thank you so much for all the help, I really appreciate it. So I stopped being lazy and came back to this to finally get this PC built. What I have picked out is the AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1900x CPU, the MSI Gaming Motherboard, and the Eva GForce GPU you have recommended to me. I asked another question here, https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/best-power-supply-unit-for-blender-cycles-rendering and am waiting 40 minutes to ask the other two questions. Thank you SO much, you have no idea how much your helping!!!!!!