# Best Power Supply Unit for Blender Cycles Rendering?

Tags: pc, power-supply

What's a very good Power Supply Unit for [this PC computer](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7857/273) I want together built meant for Blender Cycles rendering? I have a few components but need 3 more.

The three components are: the [MSI X399 board](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/8104/273), the AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X and an [EVGA GTX1080Ti FTW3](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/8130/273).

Thus the requirements in a PSU are:

- Needs to support the above components.
- Should be able to deal with an additional 1080Ti
- Needs to be ATX form-factor
- Should be relieable and not (completely) inefficient

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but my recommendation will be [the EVGA SuperNOVA 1000 G3 for $190 on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01LZ3SFB3).

Comment: Thank you SEJPM, when you do have the time do you think you can tell me why that's your recommendation and what others you may have? Also here re my other questions you told me to make: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8316/best-persistent-storage-for-blender-cycles-rendering-for-pc-im-getting-built https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8315/best-ram-for-blender-cycles-rendering-for-pc-im-getting-built

Answer (score 1):

PCPartPicker estimates your build at around 750 watts with two video cards installed.  Power supplies tend to be most efficient when loaded to about 25%-75% of capacity, so you're looking at something in the 1000W-1200W range.

I'd recommend the [SeaSonic PRIME Platinum](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817151162) in either 1000W ($210) or 1200W ($250) capacity: 1000W if the computer is going to be spending most of its time nearly idle while you do design work, or the 1200W if it's going to be running all-out for hours on end rendering.

I haven't used this particular power supply, but I've had good experience with SeaSonic power supplies in the past, and they've got a reputation for quality.  It's a high-efficiency power supply (rated 80+ Platinum, 90% efficient or above across almost the entire working range), and it's got the four 8-pin PCIe power connectors you need for your graphics cards (actually, it's got eight of them).

Answer (score 1):

**How much power do you need?**

*If* you upgrade to a second 1080Ti you will need about 250W*2+150W of power supply, plus peripherals, plus enough to catch any power usage spikes and to compensate for the sub-100% efficiency and the efficiency degradation over the years. So **1000W** is a realistic estimate for this (and a comfortably conservative one).

**So what is the recommendation?**

The [**EVGA SuperNOVA 1000-G3**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LZ3SFB3), it is an ATX form factor 1000W Gold-rated PSU with 8x 8-pin connectors for graphics cards (you will need 2 or 4 of these).

**So what are the differences between Titanium, Platinum and Gold PSUs?**

The difference between the various certifications are efficiencies. A Titanium rated PSU needs to hit 94% efficiency, a platinum 92% and a gold one 90%, so as you see there isn't *that* much of a difference. However, as you have such a large buffer with regards to power, going with a gold-rated one will do.

*Additionally* EVGA is extremely confident in the quality of this PSU, which is why they give a *decade* of warranty on it, so I wouldn't worry about build quality (and besides EVGA has an excellent reputation with power supplies).

If you want to read more about PSUs, have a look at [this article](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/evga-supernova-1000-g3-psu,4941.html) (about this PSU) and the references it links. And also note that Mark's suggestion will also be fine (and a little more efficient / with a little longer warranty for a bit more money).