# Best RAM for Blender Cycles Rendering for PC I'm Getting Built?

Tags: pc, memory

I need a really good large RAM for [a PC I want to get built](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7857/273) meant to render Blender Cycles.

**Requirements:**

- Compatibility with the [MSI X399 board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074DHQR9N).
- Compatibility with the (non-OC'ed) AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X.
- No more than 4 modules with a combined capacity of 32GB.
- Price preferably 300 USD or lower

Comment: The next up on the list of Hardware to specify is the case and then only the CPU cooler is left and you are (finally) done :)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that finding 4x8GB of DDR4 RAM with 2666 transfer speed for 300USD or less is impossible. However, I barely found this RAM, the [**G.Skill Ripjaws 4 2400 32GB** for 300USD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NOCUSQW).

- It is compatible with the board and CPU listed (which both easily support this RAM speed)
- It is within the appointed budget of 300USD.
- [Reviews](http://www.technologyx.com/pc-hardware/g-skill-ripjaws-4-3000cl15-memory-review/) of [higher-clocked variants](https://www.techpowerup.com/reviews/GSkill/Ripjaws_4_3000_16GB/) appear to look good for this series of RAM
- Being 4x 8GB it can make use of the 4 memory channels of the Threadripper
- With 15 cycles of delay, it's not the lowest-latency RAM but it should easily do the job