# Persistent Storage for Blender Cycles Rendering for PC

Tags: pc, data-storage

This is a follow up for a [previous question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7857/273) to build a high performance rendering PC. This PC will be running Windows.

**Requirements:**

- Supported by the AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X running on the [MSI X399 motherboard](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/X399-GAMING-PRO-CARBON-AC/Specification)
- Storage should be sufficient for both archived and working projects
- Maximum budget of 500 USD

Answer (score 1):

So I shall estimate that 500GB is enough for Windows, your tools (Blender + other installed programs) and the current project. To store these 500GB to which you would want quick access, I recommend the [**Samsung 960 Pro 500GB** for 290USD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LXS4TYB). Why this SSD?

- It is the fastest somewhat affordable SSD, meaning you will get GB/s transfer rates from it, which will make even large projects load instantly.
- It is a Samsung Pro series SSD, meaning it is meant to survive more write operations (which will probably happen)
- Samsung is a very reputable brand when it comes to SSD and this one is covered by a 400TBW / 5yr warranty, meaning if you write less than 220GB per day on average on your SSD, it will last you for at least five years, if not much longer, speaking for its build quality.

Now of course 500GB won't cut it if you want to archive old projects. So after you are done with your current project you'll have to move the data to your **[WD Black 4TB HDD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GWS2ZOC)** for 186USD. On this drive you have essentially 4000GB of storage available, which should be plenty for a couple of old projects. But what does the "Black" mean? It's the WD series of HDDs "for gamers" featuring technology that is supposed to make the HDD faster, however the *really nice* side-effect of this is that these technologies treat the mechanical disks inside nicer meaning the HDD will last longer than an average HDD (and WD also gives a 5yr warranty). For further reading I recommend [this guide on WD drives](https://metanophilia.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/rainbow-caviar-the-different-colors-of-western-digital-hdds/).

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a Drive that has 3 terabytes and I can keep all my current projects on that, so what does it mean to archive old projects? Like ones I created with this Mac Book Pro?

Comment: @GodzillaDude the idea is that you have enough space to keep some of your older projects on your PC (in case you need to revisit them). Much like with your current drive where you also won't be working on 5 different projects taking 100GB each at the same time (I guess?).

Comment: So your recommendation for the storage is to get the Samsung 960 500gb and the WB Black 4tb? 4tb is insane which would be great!

Comment: I think I could get the 6TB, would that be better then the 4tb?

Comment: @GodzillaDude The 6TB variant should be just about the 4TB (performance wise) variant with a better price / storage ratio for about 40USD more.

Comment: Ah okay. So I think I'm all set (excluding peripherals like the monitor, keyboard, mouse), but here is my list of what I should get. Am I missing anything? https://imgur.com/a/qiRdZ

Comment: @GodzillaDude the GPU is not on that list (intentionally?). You are also missing a CPU cooler (to transport the heat away from the CPU, this would be #2 missing) and a case (where you can actually mount all that fancy hardware).